# Excel vba chart- having problems in spliting the series to create multiple series

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded the macro to run a chart where the series is not what I am expecting
it is changing series and category in the chart

```
    Sub Macro13()

 ' Macro13 Macro
 '
 ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
 Dim myString As String
myString = Selection.Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myString),PlotBy:=xlRows
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

when I deleted the chart and ran the macro. Got the following chart

[image]

But wanted the following chart
[image]

The month-year should be on x-axis(category) and series should be 0,1,2,3 etc.
The following data is

```
series  Sep-10  Oct-10  Nov-10  Dec-10  Jan-11  Feb-11
0   7   8   90  80  110 1
1   5   1   18  36  97  1
2   5   1   18  36  97  1
3   5   1   18  36  97  1
4   5   1   18  36  97  1
5   5   1   18  36  97  1
6   5   1   18  36  97  1
7   5   1   18  36  100 1
8   5   1   18  40  97  1
9   5   7   18  36  97  1
10  5   1   89  36  97  1
11  5   1   18  36  97  1
12  5   1   18  36  97  1
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$G$14") 'was changed to 
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$G$14"), PlotBy:=xlRows then it added the series name to it but got like this with series included in x-axis
```

[image]

When I was recording macro this was the chart that I selected and removed the legend.
[image]

Comment: I am not positive on the VBA side of things but thought I would double check a couple of things with you.  1)  Are you using a line chart or and XY scatter plot?  2)   Are your dates numbers formatted to look like strings, or are they actual strings?  You can test using something like =isnumber(A2).

Comment: Line chart and It is number as =isnumber(A2) resulted in TRUE

Comment: Drop the word Series in the top left corner.  after the graph is created you can add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim obj As ChartObject, Cht As Chart
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngHead As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Set rngHead = .Range("b1", "g1")
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", "a14")
    End With
    Set obj = Ws.ChartObjects.Add(400, 200, 600, 400)
    Set Cht = obj.Chart
    With Cht
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        With .ChartTitle
            .Characters.Text = "Chart Title"
            .Characters.Font.Size = 12
        End With
        For Each rng In rngDB
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .Name = rng
                .XValues = rngHead
                .Values = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 6)
            End With
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

It is about the chart which is formed according to the dynamic range.

```
Sub setChart()
    Dim obj As ChartObject, Cht As Chart
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngHead As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngChart As Range
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngChart = Selection
    r = rngChart.Rows.Count - 1
    c = rngChart.Columns.Count - 1
    If r < 1 Or c < 1 Then
        MsgBox "set the range correctly!"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    With rngChart
        Set rngHead = .Range("b1").Resize(1, c)
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2").Resize(r)
    End With
    Set obj = Ws.ChartObjects.Add(400, 200, 600, 400)
    Set Cht = obj.Chart
    With Cht
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartType = xlLine
        With .ChartTitle
            .Characters.Text = "Chart Title"
            .Characters.Font.Size = 12
        End With
        For Each rng In rngDB
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .Name = rng
                .XValues = rngHead
                .Values = rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, c)
            End With
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The above works but I am trying to achieve- As the user  points/highlight the range and it should generate a chart by the macro. Is there a way to offset the range value to b1 so that the "Series" does not appear in the chart

Comment: @viji, What mean  Is "there a way to offset the range value to b1 so that the "Series" does not appear in the chart "

Comment: I mean instead of choosing b1. If the user select the range say A1:G14. I am changing the code to `Dim myString As String
    myString = Selection.Address           ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myString) , PlotBy:=xlRows `  Could the rngHead value change to start from b1. So that from my last but one picture where series appears on x-axis could be removed. As I want to automate as much possible just by selecting the range and running the macro should generate the chart

Comment: @viji, Added content to create flexible charts based on ranges.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the cell in the upper left corner is blank

[image: Blank]

2. Start Recording your macro
3. Select you data range

[image: Select]

4. Insert the graph style of your choosing

[image: Pick]

5. Right click on your graph and select "Select Data.."

[image: Select Data]

6. Left click on the Switch Row/Column Button

[image: Switch]

7. Format your graph to your liking
8. Add the text to the top left corner

[image: Add]

9. Stop your recording

Comment: You may still need to specify the `PlotBy`.